# function runs on document.ready instead of when told to

Tags: jquery, function, document-ready

Quite new to jQuery. I have a function which does what I want... almost. It begins like this:

```
var myFunction = function () {
    "use strict";

    jQuery(function ($) {

    //various things

    });

};
```

Things is, I want to call it when this other function happens:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    "use strict";

    $(document).ready(function () {
        anotherFunction;
        myFunction;
    });    

});
```

Instead it seems that the first function *runs by itself* when the document is ready, and `anotherFunction` is called only in a second moment.

Does it depends on the way the first function begins? Is that a good start? I looked around for examples and solutions, but there are so many different ways to start a function in jQuery I couldn't figure out which one is the one I need.

Can you help me frame these two functions, so that the first one won't run until the second one calls it?

I know I need the `jQuery(function ($)` bit otherwise browser tells me `$ is not a function`...

Comment: Based on your second bit of code there, you are calling myFunction inside of $(document).ready.

Comment: good point. but I've put a lot of `console.log` around the code, and it really seems that this happens independently, before the second function is even considered. I'm correcting the code above now to show what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function one() {
  //Do stuff
};

function two() {
  one(); //Calls first function

  //Do other stuff
}

$(document).ready(function () {
  two(); //Executes second function on doc ready
});
```

This may get you where you want to go. That said, if you don't want *anything* to execute on doc ready, you can just take that part out.

Comment: This seems clean and logical... but how do I avoid the "$ is not a function" message? Should I place the `jQuery(function ($)` thing within each function like in my original code? Or should I instead wrap the functions in a single `jQuery(function ($)` for the whole .js file? (Also, but this extra silly question can be disregarded, why there are so many snippets around that start a function with `var=`??)

Comment: Wrap all your functions in single jQuery(function($)).
Actually this is also not necessary if you are using only jquery library, just include it in script tag in <head> section like <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js" ></script> and in another script tag you can directly use $.
Also you can learn jquery from here http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/

Comment: thanks, I modified my script as suggested here. The problem is still there though. One of the functions calls an external script, the problem might be there, need to investigate...

Comment: @Ninja I have jquery in the <head> but I always get "$ is not a function" unless I call jQuery(function($))

Comment: Then you must be using any other library which removed references of $ from  jQuery.
        jQuery.noConflict() 
this relinquish jQuery's control of the $ variable.

Comment: Agree with Ninja - for instance if you are operating in legacy code that uses Prototype or the like, it will use $.